# golang filter based on key in array of map interfaces

Tags: go, interface

As part of learning, i was tried the below code snippets.

```
func ASNGroup(asn []map[string]interface{}) bool {
    eachgroup := make([][]map[string]interface{}, 0)

    for i := range asn {
        for _, v := range asn[i] {
            // How to filter the based on Key based on the below filter i should group the above asn array maps.
                    asn[i]["ID"]    
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(eachgroup)

    return true
}
```

Please help me in code and Yes i avoided struct because i m preparing the asn object based on the xlsx sheet uploaded. Yes, i know this is the mandatory key so that i can hard code this key to filter. I understand it is not as easy than javascript. for writing functions i understand there should be some return initialization i initialized dummy bool for to avoid errors.

please don't deviate the issue, with suggestions

Understand and please help in logic to group something like this [[],[]].

this is the below example of []map[string]interface{}

```
   [{"id":"1","seperator":"B","code":"twenty1"},
   {"id":"2","seperator":"A","code":"twenty2"},
   {"id":"3","seperator":"B","code":"twenty3"}]
```

seperator is the key inside object to seperate the objects.

```
{"B" : [{"id":"1","seperator":"B","code":"twenty1"},
{"id":"3","seperator":"B","code":"twenty3"}]
, "A" :  [{"id":"2","seperator":"A","code":"twenty2"}]}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your desired output?

Comment: Sure @maerics , i m updating the above question itself. Kindly check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to group all items with the same value for the identified key, often called a "group by" operation (see, for example, in JavaScript, [`_.groupBy(...)`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#groupBy))..

To implement "group by" you simply need to iterate over the given collection, lookup the value for the target key, and append the current object to the result array corresponding to the value of the key.

For example:

```
func groupBy(maps []map[string]interface{}, key string) map[string][]map[string]interface{} {
  groups := make(map[string][]map[string]interface{})
  for _, m := range maps {
    k := m[key].(string) // XXX: will panic if m[key] is not a string.
    groups[k] = append(groups[k], m)
  }
  return groups
}

func main() {
  xs := []map[string]interface{}{
    {"id": "1", "seperator": "B", "code": "twenty1"},
    {"id": "2", "seperator": "A", "code": "twenty2"},
    {"id": "3", "seperator": "B", "code": "twenty3"},
  }
  grouped := groupBy(xs, "seperator")
  // {
  //   "A": [
  //     { "code": "twenty2", "id": "2", "seperator": "A" }
  //   ],
  //   "B": [
  //     { "code": "twenty1", "id": "1", "seperator": "B" },
  //     { "code": "twenty3", "id": "3", "seperator": "B" }
  //   ]
  // }
}
```

Note that to avoid the possible "panic" in the sample code above you should use the two-value type assertion form and modify your function signature to return two values (map and error):

```
func groupBy(...) (map..., error) {
  //...
    k, ok := m[key].(string)
    if !ok {
      return nil, fmt.Errorf("expected string value type for key %q, got %T", key, m[key])
    }
  // ...
  return groups, nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Group() from https://github.com/ledongthuc/goterators#group that I created to reuse aggregate & transform functions.

[image]

```
    groups := goterators.Group(asn, func(item map[string]interface{}) string {
        return item["seperator"].(string)
    })
```

It will group elements to 1 nested level of the list by your defined criterias.

This lib requires the Go 1.18 to use that support generic + dynamic type you want to use with.